# Custom action on gestures in Asus zenbook

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, asus-laptop, mouse-gestures

I have recently bought asus ux303ln and I would like to overwrite some touchpad gestures. Only way to boot up gestures is Asus Smart Gesture and there is no option to perform custom action (like key combination) on ex. 3 finger up. I have found some solutions for Synaptic and Elan drivers, but they aren't working (can't install). Please help.